# Get middleware mount point from request in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, validation, express

I have an Express application with a router, here is the example of the router:

```
const router = require('express-promise-router')();

const users = require('./users');
const validate = require('./validate');

router.get('/users', users.list);
router.get('/users/:id', users.get);
// other routes here

module.exports = router;
```

Now I want to add a middleware that validates each query, like that (this is not the working example, it's just to show the idea of what I want to accomplish):

```
const schemas = {
    '/users': 'some validation schema',
    '/users/:id': 'another validation'
}

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
    const url = req.originalUrl; // This is where I'm stuck.

    if (!schemas[url]) {
        // throw new error that validation failed
    }

    // validating somehow
    if (!req.validate(schemas[url])) {
        // throw new error that validation failed
    }

    return next();
}
```

And for this, I need to get the middlelware mount folder (like '/users/:id' for '/users/557'). I've tried to use `req.originalUrl`, but it returns the full URL path instead of the mount folder.

How can I achieve this? And if there's no way, how can I write my validation middleware another way to make it work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Inside **req.route** you will get the path of API.

[Check this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTwO9.png)