# How to get the same route URL from request object as defined in app.use in express (Node.js)?

Tags: node.js, express

I have defined express route as below

```
    app.use('/announcement/edit/:AnnouncementId',function(req,res){});
```

Now I want to fetch the same `"/announcement/edit/:AnnouncementId"` from request object when this route is called.

When I called http://localhost:8000/announcement/edit/5a099a855f34fc3f2a7b2a9c and print log as below

```
    console.log(req.path)
```

but it gives me  `"/announcement/edit/5a099a855f34fc3f2a7b2a9c"`

I want the same `/announcement/edit/:AnnouncementId` in `req.path` or from any property of request object or any other solution.

Comment: can be duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48560445/get-middleware-mount-point-from-request-in-express/48560818#48560818

Comment: for req.route i am getting undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is simple solution, what you need to do is instead of req.path
directly check **req.baseUrl** and **req.route.path** in your final controller function

Please note that you will not get **req.route.path** in middleware.

So the solution to your problem is **req.baseUrl + req.route.path**

Another way is instead of defining routes one by one, maintain route config, create your app routes dynamically and then you will have access to route config so you can check from req.path and pattern which matched in config.

Hope it helps.